# Simple Javascript Replace not working

Tags: javascript, replace

This seems so simple and trivial but it is not working. Here is my javascript:

```
var url = "/computers/";
console.log(url);
url.replace(/\//gi, " ");
console.log(url);
```

And here is the output in my browsers console:

```
/computers/
/computers/
```

As you can see nothing changes. As you can tell from the code I'm trying to replace the forward slashes with spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
url = url.replace(/\//gi, " ");
```

Comment: man I feel a bit dumb. Thanks for that.

Comment: LoL. Epic. I just ran into this same issue and this answer saved me from emailing Brendan Eich to tell him that JS replace doesn't work :)

Comment: @greatwitenorth ㅋㅋㅋㅋ did the same mistake.

Comment: Gosh, was fighting for an hour with that. Feeling dumb as hell now. Thanks for saving me!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing changes because you're not assigning the result of the replacement to a variable. Add `url = url.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

`url.replace(/\//gi, " ");` returns the resulting string (in javascript you can't modify an existing string), you are not assigning it to anything

assign it like so:

```
url = url.replace(/\//gi, " ");
```