# Remove class of an element in Javascript using replace function

Tags: javascript

I tried a method to remove class of an element in JavaScript but it did not work can you all explain why.

```
function del() 
{
cross.className.replace("anim"," ");
}
```

cross is a element saved in a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Javascript Replace not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863257/simple-javascript-replace-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

The strings `replace()` method returns a new string with the new value. It **doesn't** modify the original string.

Here is a simple example:

```
var str = "Hello World!";
var res = str.replace("World", "Foo");

console.log(str);  // prints Hello World!
console.log(res);  // prints Hello Foo!
```

So, in your specific case, in order to make it work you have to assign the new string to `cross.className` like in the code below:

```
cross.className = cross.className.replace("anim"," ");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have to support really old browsers, you can also use the `classList` property:

```
cross.classList.remove("anim");
```

Creating your own methods for adding, removing and replacing classes can go wrong very easily. E.g.: what should happen when another class *contains* the substring `"anim"`? By using the readily available methods in the `Element` class, you're making your job a lot easier.

More on classList: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the value to class, because replace return new string with replaced text

```
function del() {
    cross.className = cross.className.replace("anim"," ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use jQuery to remove class from specific element by its id

```
$("#cross").removeClass("anim");
```